# select repeat visitors given two time periods

Tags: sql

I would like to find the percent of repeat visitors to my site. Currently I am selecting users for one month and dividing that month by the following month. to calculate those that have returned. Is this the best way to write that query?

it is yielding results that seem to be accurate, but wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

```
SELECT (
SELECT COUNT(table.user) as Total
FROM table
WHERE table.event IN ('event1','event2','event3')
AND table.month IN ('october')
) /
(
SELECT COUNT(table.user) as newTotal
FROM table
WHERE table.event IN ('event1','event2','event3')
AND (table.month IN ('october') OR table.month IN ('november'))
) AS percent_return
```

table structure looks like this, you have the same user purchasing multiple events for the same month or the same time period.

```
 order_number user month event gross

   1 jack october event2 30
   2 jack november event3 20
   3 jack november event3 20
   4 jack november event2 30
   5 sam november event2 30
   6 john october event3 20
   7 john october non_event 20
```

Comment: What is the tables' sturcture?

Comment: how do you define a "repeat visitor"? your calculation doesn't seem to explain this. when you say you want a % of repeat visitors, what is it a % of? % of repeat visitors compared to total visitors? or % of visitors who came back?

Comment: sorry by repeat visitor I meant that I will run this query multiple times substituting the month each time. like here I am running against october/november. I can run it on january/february etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two subqueries to do what you want.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (SUM(s.month IN (october)) / SUM(s.month IN (october, november))
       ) as percent_return
FROM sales s
WHERE s.event IN ('event1', 'event2', 'event3') AND
      s.gross > 0;
```

Also, there is no need for single quotes around numeric constants.

Comment: just realized this does not work because it does not select the user

Comment: @alex_b . . . What do you mean "does not select the user"?  It should be producing the same results as your original query.

Comment: the first query selects the user count, SELECT COUNT(table.user)

Comment: Does `table.user` take on `NULL` values?  That seems unlikely, but it is easy enough to add `and s.user is not null` to each of the sums.

Comment: I figured it out it was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985854/calculating-percent-return-users-using-with-sql thanks for everything.