# Calculating Percent Return Users using with SQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate the distinct users that have returned by month,
The main problem with this query I think is that it select users in october OR november I want to be AND.

```
SELECT (

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT table.user ) 
FROM table
WHERE table.month IN (october)

) / (

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT table.user ) 
FROM table
WHERE table.month IN (october,november)

)*100 AS return_users
```

table structure

```
    user month 

    jack october 
    jack november 
    jack november 
    jack november 
    sam november 
    john october 
    john october
```

Comment: How can a date be in october and november at the same time!
Same ambiguity with your recently deleted question.

Comment: Sorry fixed the query.  Want to find out what percent of users came in both months, so "returning visitors"

Comment: October saw 2 distinct users (jack and john). 1 returned in November (jack), the answer should be 50%.

Comment: Might be a better question for [DBA Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want count of distinct users that where in both October and November divided by all distinct users October.  That is, percentage of users in October that returned in November.

First, get a distinct count of all users in November that also visited in October.  This is done with an `EXISTS` to look for the previous record existing in that month for each user.

Second, get a distinct count of all users in October.

Then you just divide.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb66d9/7)

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t1.user )
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.month = 'November'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM mytable t2
        WHERE t2.user = t1.user
        AND t2.month = 'October'
    )
)
/
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT mytable.user )
    FROM mytable
    WHERE mytable.month = 'October'
) * 100
```

Comment: there is only one table.

Comment: I understand that. I am only querying one table, just aliased.

Comment: I'll try to explain the query further.

Comment: When I just run the first part of your query to return users who came in both months I get  The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Answer (score 2):

I think a much easier way to approach this type of query is with a subquery.  First aggregate at the level of the users, keeping track of whether they are in the months of october/november.  Then summarize the final results:

```
select sum(inoctober > 0 and innovember > 0) / sum(inoctober)*100 as percent_returning
from (select t.user, max(t.month in (october)) as inoctober,
             max(t.month in (november)) as innovember
      from table t
      where t.month in (october, november)
      group by t.user
     ) t;
```

Comment: Probably want to add a where clause for the months in case they decide to index it. I prefer this method to the one I responded with.

Comment: [Here you go](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb66d9/8), I added it to the SQL Fiddle I made.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand , you can set your query to be like this:

Where table.date IN (October) 
AND table.date IN (November)

INSTEAD OF:
Where table.date IN (October, November)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this makes sense but it is returning null

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this answer is correct.  How can a date be both October and November?

Comment: It should return null. because the condition will never return true.
a date can never be October AND November at the same time.

Comment: the user came in both october and november. making them a return visitor.

Comment: I Think you need to add a UNION statement which should make your query look like this:


SELECT table.user, COUNT( DISTINCT table.user ) 
FROM table
WHERE table.month IN (october)

UNION

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT table.user ) 
FROM table
WHERE table.month IN (november)

Comment: Ok, so why did you recommend making that change if it will never return a row?

Comment: I Think you need to add a UNION statement which should make your query look like this:

SELECT SUM (DISTINCT table.user)
(
SELECT table.user, COUNT( DISTINCT table.user )
FROM table 
WHERE table.month IN (october) 
GROUP BY table.user
) a
UNION 
(
SELECT table.user, COUNT( DISTINCT table.user ) 
FROM table 
WHERE table.month IN (november)
GROUP BY table.user
) b
WHERE a.table.user = b.table.user

Comment: @woot I just replied with the statement that I think it satisfies the question of alex_b as far as I understood his question.

Comment: these all make sense but none of the queries work, from your union statement I get The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns, and using AND returns 0

Comment: @AhmadNasrElKaffas I understand, and I don't mean to be offensive... but your answer couldn't be an answer to any question as a single date field can not have two dates.  In other words, there is no possible way this answer could be right given any question (aside from "How can I return no rows always?").

Comment: Please try this. I think it should be something like this. You want to get number of users that exist for both October & November.


SELECT SUM (DISTINCT table.user) 
FROM 
( 
SELECT table.user, COUNT( DISTINCT table.user )
FROM table WHERE table.month IN (october) 
GROUP BY table.user 
) a 
UNION 
(
 SELECT table.user, COUNT( DISTINCT table.user )
FROM table 
WHERE table.month IN (november) 
GROUP BY table.user 
) b 
WHERE a.table.user = b.table.user



The above query should replace your second part of your query.

Comment: @woot Yes I understand what you mean. and yes you are right. Thank you